# Replace ereg function to preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I’ve just been hit with an error on a client's website that says `ereg` has been deprecated and I’ve done a bit of Googling to find that you should use `preg_match` as it's replacement.

The only problems is, I don’t know much about the `preg_match` function and I’m also trying to understand this `ereg` function as a previous employer who is no longer here coded this website.

Any way, here’s the function and I need to know how I should go about replacing it:

```
if ( ! ereg( '/$', $sCurrentFolder ) ) $sCurrentFolder .= '/' ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original [`ereg`](https://www.php.net/ereg) seems to only be checking for a forward slash at the end of the string `$sCurrentFolder`:

```
if ( ! ereg( '/$', $sCurrentFolder ) ) $sCurrentFolder .= '/' ;
```

I believe this regex using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) should work:

```
if ( ! preg_match( '/\/$/', $sCurrentFolder ) ) $sCurrentFolder .= '/' ;
```

**EDIT:** The original poster indicates this is related to an old version of `FCKEditor` & I dug up [this fairly detailed answer](http://www.cubecartforums.org/index.php?showtopic=17945&st=20&p=73317&#entry73317) that pinpoints all of the `ereg` and `eregi` issues & suggests replacements. Be sure to look trough the whole thread. It’s a very good list and discussion of solutions if you are debugging an old install of `FCKEditor`. Although I will be honest I am not 100% sure on some of the suggestions presented.

Comment: Work? Yes. Do the same as the `ereg` version? Nope.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use a delimiter that does not appear in your regex string. I prefer parentheses as they come in matching pairs and therefore do not need escaping no matter what.

Comment: Fair enough ^_^ I know some people prefer slashes because they work in JavaScript too where there's no choice, so that's fine.

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed that it's in an old FCKEditor. I don't really want to upgrade it as it's an ancient site. Thought it would be easier to fix the deprecations. Thank you so much for this answer though, it has helped me out. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give it a read and hopefully fix up this ancient site. :p

Answer (score 3):

That thing's basically saying "if the last character is a slash", so you could use
`preg_match("(/$)",$sCurrentFolder)` or apply more cleverness:

```
if( substr($sCurrentFolder,-1) == "/") $sCurrentFolder .= "/";
```

Or even:

```
$sCurrentFolder = rtrim($sCurrentFolder,"/")."/";
// This one will remove multiple slashes from the end of $sCurrentFolder
// useful in case of possibly malformed input
```